# Multiple Filters in Rails: Category and Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have an app where a book entry belongs_to a category and a category has_many books. sample:

```
Book:        Category:
Book1        Elementary
Book2        Elementary
Book3        HighSchool
Book4        College
```

I would like to build a new **Location** Model where I can be able to show i.e: all Elementary books under a state or can go down further to a City.

this is how my current index controller looks like:

```
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @book = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @book =Book.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end

end
```

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @book = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @location_id = Location.find_by(name: params[:location]).id
        @book =Book.where(category_id: @category_id, location_id: @location_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end

end
```

Is this correct?

I'm fairly new in Rails and Relational Databases and I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how this'll work. Please let me know if you need more information. Any assistance on this topic will be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Mike B.